# Make swig command not found - When swig is installed locally

Tags: python, c++, makefile, swig

I am working on a remote server, so I have installed swig locally, using -`prefix=/home/user/directory`.

I have a makefile from a collegue which has the command :

```
swig $(SWIG_LIB) -python -c++ -threads $<, in the path home/user/dir2.
```

And when i run make i get :

> swig -I /home/theodore/swig/share/swig/3.0.7 -python -c++ -threads tagger_swig.i 
>       make: swig: Command not found**

I have googled like ages and I have found nothing that could make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add the `swig` command to your `PATH`? Alternatively you could modify the make file to specify the full path to your `swig` command.

Comment: You mean add the swig from the bin folder using the export PATH etc?

Comment: Yes, do something like `export PATH=/home/theodore/swig/bin:$PATH` (change the path to your needs) and then try `make` again.

Comment: Hmm... still i get the `swig -I /home/theodore/swig/share/swig/3.0.7 -python -c++ -threads tagger_swig.i
make: swig: Command not found
make: *** [tagger_swig.py] Error 127`, although i did what you said. At the path `swig/bin` is the executable of swig.

Comment: In the same terminal you're trying to `make` from, what happens if you execute the command `which swig`? Does it print out a path or nothing?

Comment: It worked! For some reason the change at the enviroment variable was only taken at the terminal with the export command. At the second terminal, the variable was not set. I will investigate this.

Comment: Running `export` in one terminal only sets that value for that specific terminal. To get your changes to persist and be configured in other new terminals you create, you have to modify the profile/configuration file for your shell, like [`bashrc`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work) for bash shells or `zshrc` for ZSH shells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run it by supplying absolute path to swig binary. If it works, check if swig is in your `PATH` - it probably isn't. This should fix your error.